# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{+}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{-} $ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given infinite series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$. Let $a_n^+=max(a_n,0)$, $a_n^-=min(a_n,0)$. Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely then  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{+}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{-} $ converges.

My attempt:

Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{+}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{-}$ are the partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$. Since, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, their partial sums also converge. Can we make this assumption?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely? Otherwise it's not necessarily true.

Comment: yes @carmichael561

Comment: $a_n^\pm \leq |a_n|$ for all $n$, and the result follows by comparison

Answer (score 1):

Considering that $a_n^{-} \leq 0 \leq a_n^+$, one has

$$a_n^{+}, a_n^{-} \leq a_n^{+}- a_n^{-} = |a_n|$$
Then by the comparison test, you are done.